# How do I extend the schema of an existing config_object?

Tags: 8, configuration

*Module A* defines the following schema in module_a.schema.yml.

```yaml
module_a.settings.api:
  type: config_object
  label: API settings
  mapping:
    store:
      type: string
      label: Store code
    credentials:
      type: mapping
      label: Credentials
      mapping:
        username:
          type: string
          label: Username
        password:
          type: string
          label: Password
```

*Module B* extends the *Module A* configuration form and defines additional schema properties in module_b.schema.yml.

```yaml
module_a.settings.api:
  mapping:
    additionl_one:
      type: mapping
      label: Additional one
      mapping:
        additionl_one_sub:
          type: label
          label: Additional one sub
```

The definition from module_b.schema.yml isn't picked up by Drupal. I'm checking with `config_inspector` and proving it by the fact that the new properties can't be translated.

Available articles/tutorials out there are doing the same thing but seems like this is either outdated or never worked:

- https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/post-installation/2019-02-06/add-a-new-custom-field-to-site-infomation-form-in-drupal8
- http://www.jaypan.com/tutorial/drupal-8-extending-core-configuration-extending-core-forms-and-overriding-core-routes#comment-33507

Comment: You can definitely extend configuration - it's the basis of the entire typed data API on which configuration is built. Unfortunately I don't have the answer on how to fix it, but maybe you shouldn't redefine the entire mapping, but rather try extending `module_a.settings.ap. additionl_one_sub` as `module_a.settings.api` has already been defined as a mapping in module A, so you shouldn't need to redefine it as a mapping in module B.

Comment: @Jaypan yes, it supposed to work but - it doesn't. Also, tried defining the immediately nested one but, without effect.

Comment: I have just spent a number of hours working on this - and I don't believe it's possible. I think my tutorial that is linked to used the method from the first.

Comment: @Jaypan yeah, didn't manage to make it work either, probably a d.o issue should be opened.

Comment: @xandreadx provided a working solution below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`hook_config_schema_info_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21core.api.php/function/hook_config_schema_info_alter/8.9.x).

```php
function module_b_config_schema_info_alter(&$definitions) {
  $definitions['module_a.settings.api']['mapping']['additionl_one'] = [...];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've come back to this problem multiple times in the past, and finally a solution!

Answer (score 0):

I think that I have found a solution, it seems that you need to add 'type: config_object' when extending:

```
module_a.settings.api:
  type: config_object
  mapping:
    additionl_one:
      type: mapping
      label: Additional one
      mapping:
        additionl_one_sub:
          type: label
          label: Additional one sub
```

Comment: I didn't find that this worked.